# How do you get F12 developer tools to not instantly crash and leave artifacts on your screen?

Tags: ie11-developer-tools

On two Windows 7 and a Windows 8 computer, all up to date, when I press F12 in Internet Explorer it launches the debugger, says (Not Responding), and then leaves artifacts on the screen until I restart the computer. This has been going on for a couple months.

Here is an example:

[image]

I know several other people who are experiencing the same problem on different machines.

Apparently [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/795223/ghost-context-menu-window-left-behind-when-using-context-menu) is the best Microsoft can do. Is there any way to prevent F12 developer tools from instantly crashing and leaving artifacts behind on your screen?

Comment: I don't have the problem. (Plain install of IE11 on Win7 64.) What browser addins do you have installed? I can start IE11 and toggle dev tools on and off with F12 repeatedly with no issues. Tested on two separate machines.

Comment: No add ins on any of my computers. It doesn't always happen instantly. Sometimes you have to click around. But sometimes it does happen instantly.

Comment: This is actively happening on a coworkers pc. His network profile becomes corrupt and the IT staff have to come rebuild his profile. Has been reproduced at least 3 times.

Comment: I have the same issue with Internet Explorer 11 installed on a clean Windows 10 64bit pro edition. No addons... very annoying.